# PHP Eclipse Luna on Mac doesn't have eclipse.ini

Tags: php, eclipse, macos

I am having issues with increasing Eclipse's memory allowance for all the docs say to change the eclipse.ini.

I don't have eclipse.ini file just config.ini file.

Also Eclipse is not installing in my /Applications folder its loading and running from my download folder, so its not going through a typical install.

This is the PHP Eclipse package I am using, not standard Luna Eclipse. Do I need to install standard before loading the PHP package, or is the PHP package standalone? Another thing I couldn't find an answer for with google.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse does not need any special install on Macs.

The eclipse.ini is present but Finder will not normally show it to you because it is inside of the Eclipse 'package'.

To see the eclipse.ini in Finder go to your Eclipse install directory and right click on the 'Eclipse' object and select 'Show Package Contents'. Open 'Contents' and then 'MacOS' to find the eclipse.ini file.

Comment: Ah thank you, I even went into the terminal looking for the file but it couldnt find it either.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse.ini should be in Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini